# Show all files in folder and subfolders and list names and encoding

Tags: windows, git, powershell, encoding

I want to see all the files in a folder and its sub folders and list its encoding.
I know that you can use `git ls-files` to see the files and `file*` to get the name + its encoding.
But I need help how I can do both at the same time.

The reason is that we have problem with encoding and need to see what files are encoded in what way. So I guess a PS script would work fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this by Powershell is first get your files by following Script:

```sh
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path "YourPath"
```

and in a `foreach ($file in $folder)` use one of the following scripts to get the encoding (which is straightforward)

- https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSTemplatizer/1.0.20/Content/Functions%5CGet-FileEncoding.ps1
- https://vertigion.com/2015/02/04/powershell-get-fileencoding/